# AngularJS filter:notarray error in nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I'm trying to list some data that I get from a DB, I have nested ng-repeat inside another ng-repeat. The problem is when I try to filter the results from a search, I get this error:

> Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: {}

I've tried some solutions founded here but no results...

Here is the factory who get the JSON:

```
angular.module('vSalesApp')
  .factory('listClients', function ($http) {
    return {
      list: function(callback){
        $http.get('api/call/clients').success(callback);
      }
    };
  });
```

Here is my controller:

```
 angular.module('vSalesApp')
  .controller('ClientsCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $filter, listClients) {
      listClients.list(function(listClients){
        $scope.clients = listClients;
      });
 });
```

Here is the view:

```
<input ng-model="somefield">
<div class="list-group" ng-repeat="client in clients | filter:somefield">
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item active">{{client.name}} - {{client.child_ids}}</button>
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="child in client.company_childs | filter:somefield">{{child.name}}</button>
</div>
```

The client object usualy look like this:

```
[{
    "city": false,
    "name": "Company test",
    "nrc": false,
    "child_ids": [77],
    "phone": "0123456789",
    "contact_address": "Street 1\n\n \nBelgium",
    "id": 76,
    "vat": false,
    "bank_ids": [3],
    "company_childs": [{
        "city": false,
        "name": "Delivery",
        "zip": false,
        "street2": "Delivery",
        "phone": false,
        "street": "Street 2",
        "id": 77
    }]
```

The problem comes when company_childs is empty, like this object:

```
{
    "city": "D\u00fcsseldorf",
    "name": "Federal",
    "nrc": false,
    "child_ids": [],
    "phone": false,
    "contact_address": "Willi-Becker-Allee 10\n\n40227 D\u00fcsseldorf\nGermany",
    "id": 31,
    "vat": false,
    "bank_ids": [],
    "company_childs": []
}
```

How can I manage this? I've tried ng-if or toArray:false like in the DOCS but still nothing. For each object that company_childs is empty, I get the error mentioned.

Many thanks!

edit: I have to mention that the search work properly, it filter the client and company_childs as expected.

edit2: Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G_MAN_be/Lvc0u55v/963/)
I have changed the API so I force PHP to create an empty JSON array:

```
$someArray = [];
foreach ($companies as $key) {
    if ($key['child_ids'] != null){
        $childs = $rpc->read($uid, $pwd, $key['child_ids'], array('name', 'street', 'city', 'street2', 'zip', 'phone'), "res.partner"); //here I get each child
        $key['company_childs'] = $childs;
        array_push($someArray, $key);
    }
    elseif ($key['child_ids'] == null) { 
        $key['company_childs'][] = new ArrayObject(); //If no childs, create empty array
        array_push($someArray, $key);
    }
}
return $app->JsonResponse($someArray);
```

edit3: After the modification of my API, if I copy the JSON results and paste it in my controller, I don't get anymore the error. I really don't understand why.

```
angular.module('vSalesApp')
  .controller('ClientsCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $filter, listClients) {
      $scope.clients = [{JSON array}]
  });
```

JSON lint confirm that the output of the API is an array (but empty)!

JSON output from API after JSON lint:

```
    [{
    "city": false,
    "name": "Company test",
    "nrc": false,
    "child_ids": [77],
    "phone": "0123456789",
    "contact_address": "Street 1\n\n \nBelgium",
    "id": 76,
    "vat": false,
    "bank_ids": [3],
    "company_childs": [{
        "city": false,
        "name": "Delivery",
        "zip": false,
        "street2": "Delivery",
        "phone": false,
        "street": "Street 2",
        "id": 77
    }]
}, {
    "city": "Chicago",
    "name": "Your Company, Chicago",
    "nrc": false,
    "child_ids": [73],
    "phone": "+1 312 349 3030",
    "contact_address": "90 Streets Avenue\n\nChicago IL 60610\nUnited States",
    "id": 72,
    "vat": false,
    "bank_ids": [],
    "company_childs": [{
        "city": "Chicago",
        "name": "Steven Hamilton",
        "zip": "60610",
        "street2": false,
        "phone": false,
        "street": "90 Streets Avenue",
        "id": 73
    }]
}, {
    "city": "D\u00fcsseldorf",
    "name": "Federal",
    "nrc": false,
    "child_ids": [],
    "phone": false,
    "contact_address": "Willi-Becker-Allee 10\n\n40227 D\u00fcsseldorf\nGermany",
    "id": 31,
    "vat": false,
    "bank_ids": [],
    "company_childs": []
    }]
```

edit4: I added the factory who get the clients from the API

Comment: Have you tried an `ng-if="client.company_childs.length"` on the sub ng-repeat? This may eliminate the problem.

Comment: Something like: 
`
<input ng-model="somefield">
<div class="list-group" ng-repeat="client in clients | filter:somefield">
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item active">{{client.name}} - {{client.child_ids}}</button>
  <div ng-if="client.company_childs.length"><button type="button" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="child in client.company_childs | filter:somefield">{{child.name}}</button></div>
</div>`

Comment: ng-if = "client.company_childs != []" not working?

Comment: @shteeven Yes, I've already tried `ng-if="client.company_childs.length"` and it filter correctly (doesn't show the list) but I still get the error in console.

@RanjithKumar `ng-if = "client.company_childs != []"` didn't do anythig

Comment: Can you make JS Fiddle for it

Comment: It seems that the property is `company_childs` is not an array. Are you sure that `company_childs` is an array, in the case when it is empty?

Comment: @HassanTariq here is a Fiddle : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/G_MAN_be/Lvc0u55v/963/) apparently, if I define the scope directly (without calling the API) I don't have the error anymore. 
@StepanKasyanenko I've tried to change the code in my API to force creating an array like this `$key['company_childs'][] = new ArrayObject();` I get an [object array] as expected but still get the error.

Comment: It sounds like you already have a solution, but for next time, use `console.log(res);`, like so: `listClients.list(function(res){ $scope.clients = res; });` This way you can see what your server is sending to your front end and make sure that `company_childs` is indeed an array.

Comment: @shteeven I'm sorry but I still don't have a solution... I've searched everywhere. I've already put in my question what the server is sending to my front-end. I did some modification in my PHP API to create an array (check edit2). The thing is that I get the error even before the API call as ended, I don't know why.

Comment: Why is the 'company_childs' field in the last object in the array an object? The one with the city 'Düsseldorf' has a 'company_childs' property that is an object. Did the server send that to you, or is it a typo?

Comment: @shteeven It was the old response of the server. I've corrected it, now is what the server is sending to the front end and it's an array. But I still get 3 times the same error `Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: {}` for each client that don't have childs. Still no clue why

Comment: @G_MAN_be I'm truly stumped; I can't seem to recreate your problem. Is the app on github? If so, I can fork it and try running it on my machine.